# CPtrList - How to get index of a element?

Tags: c++, mfc

How to get index of a element in the `CPtrList`?

```
class CAge
{

public:

CAge(int nAge){m_nAge=nAge;}

int m_nAge;

};



typedef CTypedPtrList <CPtrList, CAge*> CAgePtrList;

CAgePtrList list;

POSITION pos;

CAge *p1 = new CAge(21);

CAge *p2 = new CAge(40);

list.AddTail(p1);
list.AddTail(p2); 

POSITION pos1 = list.GetHeadPosition();
POSITION pos2 = list.Find(p2,NULL);
int nIndex=pos2-pos1;
```

If I subtract `pos2` from `pos1` I am getting the value `12`. I expect the value `1` since it is 2nd element.

How to get index of a element?

Comment: If you want to work with indexes, then maybe you should to use a `CTypedPtrArray` instead of `CTypedPtrList`.

Answer (score 5):

`CTypedPtrList` is implemented as a linked list. The `POSITION` pointers do not point into a contiguous array, so pointer arithmetic will not and cannot work (it's also illegal by the C++ rules).

The only way to get the index of a `POSITION` is to actually iterate backwards all the way to the beginning of the list and count the steps.

```
int nIndex = -1;

for(POSITION pos = pos2; pos; list.GetPrev(pos))
    nIndex++;

// nIndex is the 0-based index of POSITION 'pos2' in 'list'
//           or -1 if pos2 == NULL
```

Comment: ... but this is highly inefficient. A long time ago I was tasked to fix slowness in some software, and that's more or less what caused the slowness.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Right, this kind of linked list is ill-suited for index based manipulations, and I did not mean to recommend using such a list in those cases. If anything, the above shows why.